# Как дешифровать байты цезарем

Tags: шифрование

Задали такую задачку, дословный текст приведён ниже

> Упоротая коала поняла, что использовать шифр салата для кодирования текста было не очень хорошей идеей.
> Поэтому она решила зашифровать этим шифром байты, ведь тогда число возможных ключей возрастет ~ в 10 раз!
> Еще безумная коала где-то слышала, что использовать простые числа это круто!
> Поэтому она решила в качестве ключа взять простое число. Но простые числа это ОЧЕНЬ КРУТО. Поэтому для увеличения стойкости своего шифра, она решила выбрать в качестве ключа такое простое число, сумма цифр которого тоже является простым числом!
> Докажите коале, что от таких манипуляций, стойкость ее шифра только уменьшилась.***

Допустим, если этим ключом является натуральное число 11, то что делать дальше...

Ссылка на задание в [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bvforlq8gNyCpoXVVc9h1EFrVCt4CY3T?usp=share_link)

Comment: Чего тут доказывать-то? любое дополнительное ограничение снижает количество возможных паролей и, соответственно, снижает стойкость шифра.

Answer (score 0):

> Докажите коале, что от таких манипуляций, стойкость ее шифра только уменьшилась.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE current INT DEFAULT 2;
  CREATE TABLE tmp (val INT) ENGINE = Memory;
  WHILE current < 256 DO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tmp WHERE NOT (current MOD val)) THEN
      INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (current);
    END IF;
    SET current = current + 1;
  END WHILE;
  SELECT COUNT(*) keys_amount, GROUP_CONCAT(val) keys_list FROM tmp;
  SELECT COUNT(*) superkeys_amount, GROUP_CONCAT(val) superkeys_list
    FROM tmp
    WHERE (val MOD 10) + (val MOD 100 DIV 10) + (val DIV 100) IN (
      SELECT * FROM tmp
    );
  DROP TABLE tmp;
END
```

```
CALL test;
```

| keys_amount | keys_list |
| --- | --- |
| 54 | 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251 |

| superkeys_amount | superkeys_list |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | 2,3,5,7,11,23,29,41,43,47,61,67,83,89,101,113,131,137,139,151,157,173,179,191,193,197,199,223,227,229,241 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N9sK3lMp)

Число возможных ключей уменьшилось с 54 до 31, т.е. на 42.6%.

Answer (score 0):

Нафиг что-то допускать? Число может быть и другим. Но количество возможных сдвигов изначально равно количеству символов в алфавите. После решения шифровать байты алфавит в лучшем случае вырос до 256-ти символов. Если до этого не шифровались иероглифические тексты или тексты, в которых могли быть смешаны символы разных письменностей. Если же шифровалось что-то такое, то алфавит уже сократился до 256-ти (именно до 256-ти, а не до 255-ти, так как коала не обещала шифровать. То есть противник не знает, менялись ли байты вообще, читает он такой-то байт и не знает, имеется ли ввиду написанное или какое-то другое значение). Следующее решение – выбрать простой ключ. Простых чисел до 255-ти 43: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 137, 139, 149, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 211 и 227. Пока стойкость ключа всё ещё могла и увеличиться. Последнее решение – выбрать простой ключ, у которого сумма цифр тоже простая. Остаётся 22 числа: 2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 29, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 113, 137, 139, 157, 173, 179, 191, 193, 227 и 229. Остаётся перебрать все системы письменности и доказать, что символов в любом случае больше. Но алфавит дореми состоит всего из **7**-ми букв! Таким образом, доказано, что стойкость могла и вырасти. А так как шифр по условию сочинял безумец, полагаться на кириллицу и даже на латиницу нельзя.